# Validate XSD against W3 XMLSchema.xsd

Tags: c#, xsd

Any suggestions on how I can validate my XSD?

I would like to have a unit test that checks the validity of my XSD but I can't get past the following error:

> "For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method."

This seems to be because the W3 schema definition references DTDs.

This is the unit test (xUnit):

```cs
namespace MyNamespace.Profile.Test
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Schema;

    using Xunit;

    public class ProfilesSchemaTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldValidateProfilesXsd()
        {
            string profilesXsd = "Profiles.xsd";
            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => ValidateXsd(profilesXsd));
        }

        private static void ValidateXsd(string path)
        {
            const string W3Schema = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd";

            var config = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
            config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
            config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
            config.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            config.XmlResolver = null;
            config.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallBack;
            config.Schemas.Add(null, W3Schema);

            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path, config))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs validationEventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                validationEventArgs.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning
                    ? "\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred. {0}"
                    : "\tValidation error: {0}",
                validationEventArgs.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/c88ef0b0-39a8-413e-8e35-deb95fb57e58) I had a really good suggestion - use XmlSchemaSet.Compile as this validates.